# Transforming from ESRI:102173 to EPSG:4326 returning wrong results

Tags: qgis, python, pyproj

I am trying to convert a set of coordinates using ESRI:102173 system to a standard EPSG:4326 to be able to compare them with other data sets. The issue I am having is than when converting the values using pyproj or https://epsg.io/ I get results that are out of bounds for the ESRI:102173 CRS. For example the point (0, 650987) appears to be in Germany when the bounds for the original system should not extend that far west.

When loading the data on QGIS all points appear to be correctly displayed when using the ESRI:102173 values, however points near the bounds appear displaced by hundreds of kilometers. Is there a fix to this, or should I try converting the other data sets from EPSG:4326 to ESRI:102173?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You should first make sure what CRS the data is saved in. Then you can try to transform. Without sharing (sample) data or getting more information, it is difficult to help